# GitLab Error: Connection Refused

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a cloud server from Digital Ocean that is hosting `GitLab`.

Whenever I try to create a repository and push it to GitLab, I am getting the following error  :

> ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I am fairly new to git so I am confused why I keep getting this error. I also have generated and added my SSH key to GitLab. Here are the steps I take to create the repository (per GitLab's instruction):

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@idAddress
git push -u origin master
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You can test your SSH key authentication with:

`$ ssh -T git@yourhost.com`

Check that your public key is saved in your Gitlab profile, and make sure no newlines are present in the string. Then check that git is using your correct private key if you have more than one.

Also consider that Gitlab may require the repository to exist; the push won't create a new repo.

Comment: After running your suggested command, I received the message `Welcome to GitLab, JT!`. Is this what I should receive if my public key is setup correctly?

Answer (score 1):

> localhost port 22: Connection refused

Means Git tried to connect to SSH (port `22`) to your local host (`localhost`), and nothing was listening on that port — hence `Connection refused`.

You mention `ipAddress` in your setup, is it `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: At first I had it as `localhost` because I didn't follow the proper installation instruction when initially setting up the server. However, I changed it to the IP address of the server and it still didn't work.

Comment: @JTWheeler, I mean, you cited `localhost` in the error message. It this still correct *now?* Or do you get a similar error message (connection refused on port 22), just for a different host? If yes, this means the SSH server isn't listening (it is it which serves connections on port 22). Otherwise check to be sure that your remote "origin" does not point to `localhost` but to the new IP address.

Comment: Correct, I still receive the same error (connection refused on port 22). I will double check that the remote origin does not point to `localhost`. Thanks!